# border-right is little bit down from border-top

Tags: html, css

(Sorry for the bad title, don't know how to name this correctly)

html:

```
<header>
  <div id="">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="menu_btn">my menu</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="menu_btn">my menu2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="menu_btn">my menu3</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="menu_btn">my menu4</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


header {
  border-top: 3px solid #107dcc;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #CED3DC;
  top: 0;
}

.menu_btn {
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  float: left;
  border-top: 3px solid #CED3DC;
  border-right: 1px solid #107dcc;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100px;
}
.menu_btn:hover {
     border-top: 3px solid #107dcc;
}
```

When you hover the mouse over menu2, 3, or 4, the top right corner is ok, but you can see something little wrong is about the top left corner.

I mean, it seems about 1 px is missing from the outer side.

What I did wrong? I just need a straight top left corner, (as the right corner is).

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mwqpsfd3/2/

Comment: No the answer, but zooming in the left and right border don't go to the top to start with. Your problem is right there.

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, but what was wrong for left and right borders, this is what I dont get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to correct top left border then you can't use border. You can use ::before css to correct this.

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }


    header {
      border-top: 3px solid #107dcc;
      height: 55px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #CED3DC;
      top: 0;
    }

    .menu_btn {
      height: 38px;
      line-height: 38px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
      float: left;
      border-right: 1px solid #107dcc;
      font-size: 14px;
      width: 100px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .menu_btn::before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 3px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #107dcc;
      display: none;
    }
    .menu_btn:hover:before {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
      <div id="">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="menu_btn">my menu</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="menu_btn">my menu2</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="menu_btn">my menu3</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="menu_btn">my menu4</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
```